# making a function C#

Tags: c#, function, readprocessmemory

I am making a simple C# trainer, in which I use `ReadProcessMemory`.

At the moment I do it like this:

```
RPM(base,buffer) --> buffer+offset1=finaladdress --> RPM(finaladdress,buffer) -->  
BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0) = value
```

Now I want to automate the process using a function (because the process is to messy for multilevel pointers).

I found this:

```
uint []offsets = {0xDFCDD8, 0x13A8, 0x4}
getAddress(offsets);

uint getAddress(offsets[])
{
    int i;
    uint address;
    address = readProcessMemory(offsets[0]);
    for(i=1; i<(sizeof(offsets)/sizeof(uint)); i++)
    {
        address = ReadProcessMemory(address + offsets[i]);
    }
    return address;
}
```

But I do not understand how this works. Can anyone explain it to me or give me an other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is not quite valid C# code so that may be a little bit why you are having trouble understanding it. but basically it appears to do exactly what you where talking about doing manually, it just does a redirection for each element in the array.

Here is a re-written version that would be valid code plus a few tweaks to make it easier to describe what is going on.

```
int GetValueForLives()
{
   uint[] offsets = {0xDFCDD8, 0x13A8, 0x4}
   uint uncastValue = GetAddress(offsets);
   int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(uncastValue, 0);
}

uint GetAddress(uint[] offsets)
{
    int i;
    uint address;
    uint result = readProcessMemory(offsets[0]);
    for(i=1; i < offsets.Length; i++)
    {
        address = result + offsets[i]
        result = ReadProcessMemory(address);
    }
    return result;
}
```

So what `GetAddress()` is doing is basically doing your old manual method with 2 redirections.

```
RPM(0xDFCDD8,result) --> address = result + 0x13A8 --> RPM(address,result) --> 
    address = result + 0x4 -->  RPM(address,result)
```

It then returns the value for `result`, after that `GetValueForLives()` takes that `uint` value and turns it into a `int` value then returns that `int` value to the caller.